# Borderlands Xbox: I''ve just finished it...but outstanding medals to be won?

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands

Rather than being pleased I found myself quite depressed! Killed the big baddie and handed in the key. And now what? I'm level 36, but I've seen that some people are level 50+ - how?

I've realised that I've not earned all the medals - obviously I've been to methodical and not gone around causing mayhem and killing more people, spiderants, and opening more boxes, etc, etc, etc. How can I have missed out on so many medla when I have killed most things in front of me and have been everywhere, and opened as many chests as I can as I've followed the story line?

So, what's the next stage for a Borderlands fan?

- Can I play it again with the same character; at the same level that I am now, but face tougher opponents early on?
- Do I change character and try someone else? And would that start me from level 1 again?
- Go online and have done with single player?
- Buy bad company 2 or Dirt2?

Many thanks for any pearls of wisdom.

Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have finished the game the first time you will have the option to restart the game with that character as they currently are and start a Play Through 2. The story is the same just with tougher bad guys. After the character selection you will be asked to choose play through 1 or play through 2.

There is currently a 2.5 play through mode too, in which once you reach the Big Bad in Play Through 2 all mobs will be level 48-51.

The 2.5 mode will be made redundant by patch 1.4.1 which will scale the game to your level rather than have fixed levels. (1.4.1 will also add 8 levels to the game, raiding the non DLC-3 max to 58 and the DLC 3 max to 69.)

New characters start at level 1, on the bus. If you are looking to get all the achievements you will need to level all 4 at least high enough to get 15 kills with each of their special powers (though the Lilith achievement only requires 1 kill).

Playing Borderlands on line, with friends is a lot more fun than solo Borderlands.

Comment: Cheers. I started it up last night and began my playthrough 2 with the same character - badder baddies and bigger guns! Loving it. I'm off tomorrow to buy a Xbox live gold card so I can get involved online. Great game!!!

Answer (score 2):

36 sounds like a pretty typical level to end the game at. Sounds about right with what I ended at.

I can only answer specifically to your first question. Yes, you can play with the same character and start again from the beginning. Your stats and weapons and everything carry over with you and the opponents are tougher to start with. I think you get achievements for popping level 40, and then again for 50.

There are four different DLC packs out that you can download (for points) to extend the experience, but beware that some of them are very hard if you're starting at 36. Zombie Island of Dr. Ned you really need to be at about level 40 to compete in it. I'm not familiar with the Mad Moxxi DLC, and The Secret Armory of Dr. Knoxx you can't even try until you're closer to 50. I'm not familiar with what level you need to be for the new DLC, Claptraps Robot Revolution. I picked up the 2 DLC i have when they were on sales. I think they were worth the money spent.

Comment: Thanks. I feel a playthrough 2 coming on, but how do you start a playthrough 2? Will it happen automaticaly when I turn on the console tonight and select to play as per usual?

Comment: Can't quite remember without being at my console, but I think you just start another playthrough and select your existing character. It's not too hard to figure out.

Comment: Speaking of levels, the Knoxx DLC raises the level cap to 61, and there will be a free title update within the next couple weeks that will raise the level cap an additional 8 levels (to 58 or 69 depending on if you have the Knoxx DLC).

Comment: Another clarification, playthrough 2 is a full playthrough that allows you to replay the entire game, completing every quest again. You can switch back and forth between the two playthroughs, and you character will be the same between them. For example, if you loot a sweet weapon in playthrough 2, you can go back to playthrough 1 and still have that weapon. Also, all 4 DLCs allow you to play through them on both playthrough 1 and playthrough 2. There also is something called playthrough 2.5 after you beat playthrough 2 which ups the enemies again.